# CentOS filesystem mount

Tags: linux, centos, filesystems, mount

I have set up a CentOS server and am administering it using Webmin. (I know webmin is generally frowned upon, but it is how I was taught to work on Linux and I only know basic ssh)
The root drive available is small (virtual machine option) and I am attaching a secondary drive.
I need to mount it and on my first attempt, this failed miserably and the server was unreachable.
My question is, does the filesystem have to match that of root i.e. root shows as xfs, should the new mount be that as well or what is the preferred type.
Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit difficult to understand (ie its difficult to understand how you are attempting to do the mount, so I can't really advise why its failing), but

No, a mounted filesystem can be any type the kernel can recognise, and different files can, and are commonly, different to the root system.  (NFS is a prime example, as is mounting USB keys which use FAT32, but its quite arbitrary).

Comment: Thank you for the response. I received response back from the hosts of the virtual machine and they say that the partition on the drive that was mounted is most likely corrupt. When this was removed from fstab, the machine was able to boot. As mentioned before, I used Webmin to mount the drive, which I have never done before and wanted to check that it wasn't my selection that caused the problem. This is what I see when I use webmin http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/Disk_and_Network_Filesystems#The_Disk_and_Network_Filesystems_module

Comment: Have you partitioned the new drive ?  And what am I supposed to be seeing in the webmin screenshot ?